unable to start Vue Js 2 on Laravel 10
working with Laravel 10 and installed Vue Js 2 on the Laravel project. I have following vite.config.js file as well
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue2';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});

but when I stat the project using npm run dev I got following error msgs
failed to load config from F:\2021 Technics\vue + laravel\fullstackblog\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error: Cannot find module 'node:path'
Require stack:
- F:\2021 Technics\vue + laravel\fullstackblog\node_modules\vite\dist\node-cjs\publicUtils.cjs
- F:\2021 Technics\vue + laravel\fullstackblog\node_modules\vite\index.cjs
- F:\2021 Technics\vue + laravel\fullstackblog\vite.config.js
- F:\2021 Technics\vue + laravel\fullstackblog\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-41cf5ffd.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\2021 Technics\vue + laravel\fullstackblog\node_modules\vite\dist\node-cjs\publicUtils.cjs:3:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Object._require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (file:///F:/2021%20Technics/vue%20+%20laravel/fullstackblog/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-41cf5ffd.js:66358:17)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `vite`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Nalaka\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-17T16_08_37_891Z-debug.log

how could I fix this error ?
